# How to solve this logarithmic system of equations

Tags: logarithms

I was trying to solve this system and I tried to express $y = \frac{100}{x}$ from the first equation and change into the second one and I got $\frac{100}{x}\log_{10}{x} = 10$ After some work I got to $x = 10\log_{10}{x}$ And I cannot solve this one.

$\begin{cases}xy = 100 \\ y\log_{10}{x} = 10\end{cases}$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that there are log rules that may help. For instance, $y\log_{10}x=\log_{10}x^y$.

I think after employing this rule, you may be able to see the answer. What is $\log_{10}x^y=10$ actually saying, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: From the second equation we get
$$y=\frac{10}{\log_{10}{x}}$$
plugging this in the first one
$$\frac{x}{\log_{10{x}}}=10$$ so $$x=10\log_{10}{x}$$
Here you will need a numerical method.
From here we get the simpler equation
$$10^{x/10}=x$$
With $$y=\frac{10}{\log{10}{x}}$$ we get

$$\frac{10x}{\log_{10}{x}}=100$$

Comment: So it is basically $x^2=x^{10}$?

Comment: @Raptor No. It's $x^2=10^x$

Comment: Oh, my bad! Transposition error. That means OP's $x=10\log_{10}x$ is wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't you get $y=\frac{10}{log_{10}x}$ from the second equation?

Comment: Yes this is true, just a typo! Thank you,corrected!

Comment: Then, plugging that into the first equation, I think all of your $2$s should be $10$s. Ultimately you wind up at $x=10\log_{10}x$, where the OP had reached.

Comment: Yes $$100/10=10$$ oh man,sorry thousend times